# Api doesn't display anything on call

Tags: jquery, html, api

I'm trying to build a little website for school, I've to call an API and get the data with jQuery to display it in my HTML. 
But I don't know why it doesn't want to work while I'm calling it just as any API.

Here is my code that doesnt work :

```js
$.getJSON("http://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=rick-&-morty&embed=episodes&fbclid=IwAR3ELV6z5JquoLAP5TQQ1z0Ifw3-1zEu2ZYv0DDAU1yBzsj_TVMHid8LTjM", function(json) {
  var info = json;
  $("#name").append("Name : " + info.name);
});
```

```css
/* CSS files add styling rules to your content */

body {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #373fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <!-- full width div by default -->
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="city"></h1>
  </div>
  <!-- end of div with "container" class -->
</div>
<!-- end of #header -->

<div id="content" class="container">
  <!-- second "container" -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">

      <span id="name"></span> <br />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you try to switch the api link with this one : https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Paris&units=metric&appid=b0ce16829d2797b1f7e13b46746aa4e2 it does work, hence why I don't understand where does the problem come, from me both should do the trick.

Thank you for your help, I'm beginning with API and jQuery so it might be something stupid.

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console? The API may not allow CORS.

Comment: @Barmar oh it does have this error `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sulfuric-empress.glitch.me/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.tvmaze.com/singlesearch/shows?q=rick-&-morty&embed=episodes&fbclid=IwAR3ELV6z5JquoLAP5TQQ1z0Ifw3-1zEu2ZYv0DDAU1yBzsj_TVMHid8LTjM'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Change to `https:` in the API call.

Comment: It does work, lol, thank you for that!